# audioread() or waveread() of matlab in java

Tags: java, matlab, audio, audio-recording

How I can convert the `audioread()` or `waveread()` of `matlab` in `java` as these two functions are not supported by `matlab` coder. I really need one of them for my project.

OR

How can I get the double result that these two functions of `matlab` are creating from an audio file using `java` function.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any Java class that supports the reading of a wave (.wav) file. For example: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

Comment: Thanks dear.Now i can get double values like MATLAB.